# Reading in one file and writing out to another fails

Tags: java, android, eclipse, text-files

I want my app to update its information from one textfile to another. It works at another place in my code, but here, even though it seems to be exactly the same, it doesn't work.

The program goes through a `while` loop until the file has no `nextLine`. The first 5 lines in the file are the player scores and the second 5 are the player names. I currenty have it working perfectly through the first five but when it comes to the names it messes up: It reads in name 1, misses name 2 and then reads the remaining 3. At this point it breaks out of the `for loop` and restarts the `while` loop because (I think) the program knows it's missed a line. It then reads in name 2 and overrides score 1 with it, and finally attempts reading again at which point it crashes.

```
        while(!readDone)
        {
            System.out.println("!Done");
            while (readFile.hasNextLine())
            {
                System.out.println("second While Loop");
                for(int j = 0;j<10;j++)
                {
                    if(j<5)
                    {
                        System.out.println("For Loop!" + j + "scores");
                        score[j] = readFile.nextLine();
                        System.out.println(score[j]);
                    }
                    if(j==5 || j>5)
                    {
                        System.out.println("For Loop!" + j + "names");
                        usernames[j-5] = readFile.nextLine();
                        System.out.println(usernames[j-5]);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Exit For Loop");
                readDone = true;
            }   
            System.out.println("Exit second while");
        }
        System.out.println("DONE");
```

Any ideas on why this might be happening from the code above? I am printing out to the LogCat console, so I know it's missing name 2.

Comment: how is this Android related?

Comment: beacause i'm using android

Comment: What do you mean 'it breaks out of the if'?

Comment: sorry i meant the `for` loop when it reaches j = 10

Comment: For one, your `readFile.hasNextLine()` is in the wrong place.

Comment: Get rid of some of the loops (hint: one is enough) and check the content of your input file.

Comment: I've got rid of the extra while loop still get the same problem. and the input file is exactly as epected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Henry I found the problem. It showed the items as a list as expected. However when i went through it character by character there was a space after the name. This is why it was missing out six and printing out a blank line instead.